# NullReferenceException when changing text from class

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I tried to change a `TextBox` text from another class by doing this :

my form1:

```
public void showLog(string s)
{
      txtlog.Text = s;
}
```

and my class:

```
class Functions
{

    private readonly Form1 form;
    public Functions(Form1 form)
    {
        this.form = form;
    }

    public Functions()
    {

    }
    private void FindDlLinks(string url)
    {
        // line bellow gave me a NullReferenceException error
        form.showLog("something");
    }
}
```

And the error is :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

it works with a simple `MessageBox` but seems there is something with my `TextBox`.

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: When you calling FindDlLinks() method make sure your form field is not null, I think in FindDlLinks() method form field is null, are you creating new Functions(Form1 form) cunstractor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send `this` as parameter to the `constructor` when you are instantiating an instance of `Functions`. Like this:

```
Functions fr = new Functions(this);
fr.FindDlLinks("");
```

Comment: thanks for your help